# Storing private data in a thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I need to know if I can store private data for a thread in the following way.

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, student, (void *) i);

void *student(void *arg) {
    int mybooks[3];
    int mybooks_index = 0;

    .......
}
```

Is this possible or is the only way of doing is sending a pointer to a struct as an argument when i create the thread?

Comment: `mybooks` and `mybooks_index` are *automatic* variables. I would hope each thread has their own (since you didn't make either `static`).

Comment: That's the idea, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each thread has its own stack. `mybooks` and `mybooks_index` are automatic variables and thus allocated on the stack (i.e. per thread). They are only deallocated when `student` exits. So yes, this will work. If you had made them `static`, they would be shared between threads rather than be private to the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Each thread you spawn with an entry point of `student` will have their own copy of `mybooks` and `mybooks_index`.  As noted by @WhozCraig, they are automatic variables.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by storing private data in a thread like that ? Are you asking if mybooks array will be accessible in the "student" function? Yes it will be. Is this a good practice ? Depends on what you are trying to accomplish. I would suggest you to create a class for a book, called Book. Then you pass an object type of Book to the function that you are calling in the thread ( student() in your case ).

Comment: @abligh, then just use a struct instead of a class. Same thing. No difference at all. Except that everything you define in a struct is implicitly taken as public, while in the class as private. Unless you make use of the private and public keyword explicitly in the class or struct declaration.